# Announcing a Pro Tempore election

Tags: discussion, election

**Summary**: Engineering will begin the nomination stage for [a special election](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/election/1) on **August 27, 2018** to bring in two moderators.

For full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). The timeline goes something like this:

- Between now and Aug. 27, users can decide whether to nominate themselves and ask questions of candidates on meta. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- Between Aug. 27 and Sept. 3, users may nominate themselves and answer any questions that might have been asked on meta.
- On September 3, if there are three or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll simply appoint the candidates. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on the eleventh.

(Note for current moderators: there's no need to nominate yourself even though you'll likely get an email saying you should.)

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

Comment: Jon - thanks for getting this put together.  I know you have had a lot on your plate lately.

Comment: @GlenH7: No problem at all. It's nice to have a project that is clearly good for communities. ;-)

Comment: I don't always like his answers and comments but Solar Mike is very active.

Comment: @paparazzo as these are volunteer positions that come with a potentially non-trivial amount of responsibility, users may only nominate themselves and not others.

Comment: There are 2 nominations for 2 positions. Is it necessary to go ahead with the election? We already know the outcome.