# Moderator Election Question: How to attract active netizens

Tags: discussion, election

This is a question to be answered by wannabe moderators (per [Announcing a Pro Tempore election](https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/560/33)).

> There have been many times where the answer is on Meta "Have the community nominate it for deletion" or "have the community flag for changes".  On larger sites, many people sit back while those who are involved do the work, while our small group of several highly active individuals struggles some days to find the people to close out a question.  Therefore, if you were elected, how would you attempt to attract and continue to hold onto new useful users that are willing to flag things for closing and keeping the site actively maintained?